# PHP mail being sent more than once with different time stamps

Tags: php, email

I am using PHP to preload a PHP form based on MySQL data and current time.  The user selects name from a  list and enters their e-mail, if they want a confirmation email.  The rest of the form is a set of  lists and radio buttons.  On submit click, the following PHP is called:

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Confirmation</TITLE>

 <?php
       error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1'); 

        //session_start();

        //if(isset($_SESSION['run']))
        //{
    //   exit();
        //}

        $today = getdate();
        $d = $today['mday'];
        $m = $today['mon'];
        $y = $today['year'];
        $h = $today['hours'];        
        $n = $today['minutes'];
        $now = $y . "-" . $m . "-" . $d. " " . $h . ":" . $n . "";

        $sent = False;

        $Week = $_GET["Week"];

        //Exit if user did not identify themself
        If(isset($_GET["User"]))
        {
           $User = $_GET["User"];   
           If($User == 0)
           {
              Header("Location: myform.php?try=1");
              exit;
           }
        }
        Else
        {
           Header("Location: myform.php?try=1");
           exit;
        }

        $To =  $_GET["to"];
        If(isset($_GET["from"]))
        {
           $From = $_GET["from"];
        }
        Else
        {
           $From = "";
        }

        // Connect to database server
        //Big Block of Code that Queries Database, Inserts records in database and
        //creates HTML and Text strings

        If($From <> "")
        {
           $Efrom = "-f <" . $From . ">";
           $HFrom = $From;
        }
        Else
        {
           $Efrom = "-f <" . $To . ">";
           $HFrom = $To;
        }

        $headers = "From:" . $HFrom . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";


        If($sent != True)
        {
           mail($To,"Weekly Picks for " . $User, $HTML . "<br />" . $strText ,$headers, $Efrom);
           If($From <> "")
           {
            mail($From,"Weekly Reports" . $User, $HTML . "<br />" . $strText ,$headers, $Efrom);
           }
            $sent = True;
        }

        //$_SESSION['run'] = "Ran";


    // Close the database connection
    mysql_close();  

?>

<BODY background="mybackground.jpg" TEXT="black" >

<?php echo $HTML; ?>

<center><h3><a href="http://www.myhome.html">Return Home</a></h3></center>

</BODY></HTML>
```

The problem is that the e-mail is sent about 4 times, each time about 1 - 2 minutes apart.  The $now variable is part of the HTML and text string ($HTML, $strText) that are the subject of the email. The $now variable will increment by 1 - 2 minutes each email.  The $_SESSION['run'] and $sent variables are hacks that were implemented to try to avoid the problem.  $strText is just a plain text version of the $HTML in case the $HTML does not render in the user or my browser.

Obviously the PHP code is being called multiple times, but why?  Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling this page? Can you add the PHP for that? Is it called directly as a `<form>`'s action attribute? Is it included in another page? Do you use a `header()` call to get here?

Comment: It is called as the form's action attribute.  I do not use a Header() call to get here.  Hosted at 000webhost.com.

Comment: In that case, it should only be called when you click Submit. The only thing I can think of is that you're controlling whether the email is sent using the `$sent` variable, but that will have no effect - it'll always be set to False when this code runs. So an email will be sent every time this page is called and it passes the validation.

Comment: Exactly,  The $sent was a hack.  with or without the $sent and with or without the $_SESSION['run'] variables, its still sending the email about 4 times.  Is it "re"-validating the page (and thus executing the PHP) every 1-2 minutes?

Comment: It shouldn't be - it should only be run when it's called; and if it's the action of a form, that means that it should only be called when someone hits the submit button. Once I've hit submit, my email shouldn't be sent again.

Comment: I'd suggest some more details debugging - does it behave like that when you submit the form? How about if you don't complete the form and hit submit? What if just some of the fields are filled in? Can you add more to the emails that are being sent - maybe include everything from `$_GET`, and see if you can use that to replicate things.

Comment: Different but maybe related issue, The $HTML variable renders a 2 column table with about 10 rows +/- (depending on form data) with white font and dark background.  When I echo $HTML on the page, it looks fine but often (not always) in the email about the 5th or 6th row has a white background (so you can't read the text in that row unless you highlight it with your cursor).

Comment: It's also possible that because you're using `$_GET`, the form is re-submitted if someone navigates back to the same page. That might also be an issue.

Comment: The page is in development.  No one is navigating back to the same page between the email sends.  I typically use $_POST but when using $_POST it was returning false on every isset($_POST["AnyVariable"]) check.

Comment: So is it just you who's using this page at the moment? Or are there other people working on the site?

Comment: I am the only one using the site.

Comment: So you're submitting the form; and getting an email promptly from that. And then over the next few minutes, more copies of the same email are arriving, with different timestamps? Do they all have exactly the same information?

Comment: andrewsi -- Yes, they all have the same information (except the timestamp).  Eliminated both the $_SESSION['run'] and $sent hacks and ran last night.  This time, I got my confirmation email immediately, then I got a second about 30 minutes later and a third about an hour and a half after that. All three of those went to the $From.  The $To only got the one email.

Comment: Can you go into the emails and open up the headers? I'm wondering if your mailserver is responsible, because you shouldn't be seeing that behaviour from the code. In each email, there should be a `Message-ID` header line. Can you compare those?

Comment: <20130829134455.BABC2103A39@srv25.000webhost.com>

Comment: Is that the same for each of the emails you're getting?

Comment: Test 3, Message 2 (9:44) = <20130829134455.BABC2103A39@srv25.000webhost.com>; Test 3, Message 1 (9:43) = <20130829134307.515441039FA@srv25.000webhost.com>; Test 2, Message 3 (9:45) = <20130829134542.C708F103A5E@srv25.000webhost.com>; Test 2, Message 2 (9:33) = <20130829133311.44AA4103A71@srv25.000webhost.com>; Test 2, Message 1 (9:31) = <20130829133146.AC0D2103A5D@srv25.000webhost.com> ...... ect ...  Each message appears to have a unique Message-ID.

Comment: Well, I'm at a loss, in that case. That means that they're separate emails, rather than the same one being sent multiple times by the server; and that should only happen when the page is loaded. The only other suggestion I can think of is to use `var_export($_SERVER, true)` to add the contents of the request to your email - you'll be able to see where the request came from, when it was made, and so on.